# Is creating the date of tomorrow like this going to give an error?

Tags: php, date

I want to have the date of tomorrow stored as a parameter in php.

```
$vandaag = date(DATE_ATOM);
$morgen = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$morgen = date(DATE_ATOM, $morgen);
```

This is the code that I have and it works but I'm not sure if this will give problems at the end of a month. Is mktime smart enough to avoid such problems or do I need to do this another way?

Comment: `strtotime("tomorrow")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime()` from PHP

Code will look something like:

```
$vandaag = new DateTime();
$vandaag->modify('+1 day');
```

Ref.: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following:

```
 $morgen = (new DateTime())->modify("+1 day");
```

This will always give you the date exactly 24 hours from now.